# Matplotlib shifts line plots along the xaxis inadvertently

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot three lines from different Pandas Dataframes to the same subplot in matplotlib. But, when I did this I found one of the plots shifted along the xaxis (The xrange is different for each line). However, when I plot each line individually the xlimits are correct and none of them are shifted. I have tried to reproduce my problem here:

```
def plot_dH1(title1, title_sim, a, b, c):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
    plt.style.use(‘ggplot’)
    sns.set_style(‘ticks’)
    plt.rcParams[‘font.size’] = 15 

    n = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):  
        ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,n+1)

        ax = a[i].groupby(level=(0, 1)).mean()[0].plot(label=‘$\chi_{180}$‘)
        ax = b[i].groupby(level=(0, 1)).mean()[0].plot(label=‘All’)
        ax = c[i].groupby(level=(0, 1)).mean()[0].plot(label=‘$\chi_{90}$‘)

        ax.set_ylabel(‘$dH$‘)
        ax.set_xlabel(‘$\lambda_{0}$, $\lambda_{1}$‘)
        ax.set_title(title_sim[i])

        title = title_sim[i]
        sns.despine(offset=10, ax=ax)
        plt.xticks(rotation=90) 
#         plt.yticks(range(0,350,20),range(0,350,20))

        n = n+1

    lgd = ax.legend(loc=‘upper center’, bbox_to_anchor=(0.35, -0.8),fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=3)
#     plt.tight_layout()
#     fig.savefig(‘{}.pdf’.format(‘dHdl_all’))
    fig.savefig(‘{}.pdf’.format(‘dHdl_all’),bbox_extra_artists=(lgd,), bbox_inches=‘tight’)

array = [range(10), range(10,20)]
tuples = list(zip(*array))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)

a = [pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,1), index=index)]
b = [pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,1), index=index[5:])]
c = [pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8,1), index=index[2:])] 

plot_dH1(title1, title_sim, a, b, c)
```

a, b, c are lists of Pandas Data Frame. I am not able to upload an image. But if you run it you will see the problem. Does anyone knows why one of the lines is shifted along the xaxis?

Answer (score 0):

You'll get answers quicker and more reliably if you can provide a minimal, working example. Your supplied code was missing several imports that were renamed, the title definitions, and had several commented lines cluttering things. Using the following code, I see that all of the lines start with the same x shift:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def plot_dH1(title1, title_sim, a, b, c):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
    plt.style.use('ggplot')
    sns.set_style('ticks')
    plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 15 

    n = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):  
        ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,n+1)

        ax = a[i].groupby(level=(0, 1)).mean()[0].plot(label='$\chi_{180}$')
        ax = b[i].groupby(level=(0, 1)).mean()[0].plot(label='All')
        ax = c[i].groupby(level=(0, 1)).mean()[0].plot(label='$\chi_{90}$')

        ax.set_ylabel('$dH$')
        ax.set_xlabel('$\lambda_{0}$, $\lambda_{1}$')
        ax.set_title(title_sim[i])

        sns.despine(offset=10, ax=ax)
        plt.xticks(rotation=90) 
        n = n+1

    lgd = ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.35, -0.8),fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=3)
    fig.savefig('{}.pdf'.format('dHdl_all'),bbox_extra_artists=(lgd,), bbox_inches='tight')

array = [range(10), range(10,20)]
tuples = list(zip(*array))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)

a = [pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,1), index=index)]
b = [pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,1), index=index[5:])]
c = [pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8,1), index=index[2:])] 
title_sim = np.arange(10)
title1 = ''

plot_dH1(title1, title_sim, a, b, c)
```

produces the following plot using Python 3.5.2:

[image: offset picture]

I don't see an x shift of one of the three curves plotted relative to the other two. An x offset is defined, and is controlled by the `offset` parameter of the line `sns.despine(offset=10, ax=ax)`. Setting it to zero makes all of the lines adjacent to the y-axis:

[image: no offset picture]

Answer (score 0):

No, Dataframe b is acutually shifted. Look at the blue curve. Its index are defined as index[5:] which means that it should have these values:

```
[             0
 5 15  1.398019
 6 16  0.325211
 7 17  0.113059
 8 18  0.814993
 9 19  0.402437]
```

So it should start from (5 15) along the X axis, but it is actually starting from (2, 12), which means that it is shifted.